# Scala's sealed in python

Tags: python, sealed-class

How might I get the benefits of scala's [sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203268/what-is-a-sealed-trait) [class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html#sealed-classes) in python? That is, to make it possible to subclass a class only in the module in which it's defined.

**Note** not a dupe of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564198/pythons-equivalent-of-nets-sealed-class). C# `sealed` is equivalent to scala's `final`.

An example of where I might want this is to define an array type, and specify in that type what its shape is as follows

```
from typing import final, TypeVar, Generic
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

S = TypeVar('S', bound=Shape)


class Array(ABC, Generic[S]):
    @abstractmethod
    def shape(self) -> S:
        pass


class Shape(ABC):  # how to make this sealed, or similar?
    pass


@final
class Shape1(Shape):
    pass


@final
class Shape2(Shape):
    pass


def fn(arr: Array[Shape2]):
    # some calculation that requires it to be a rank-2 array
```

As it is, someone can inherit from `Shape` and make their own rank 2 shape, which wouldn't be accepted by `fn`, even though it's valid (sure it's not necessarily a good idea to do that, but users can do what they like).

Other examples are making proper enums. I know there isn't pattern matching, but I imagine it would be confusing to define an `Either` type and for someone to make a third subclass.

Comment: @jonrsharpe c# sealed is different from scala sealed afaik

Comment: Could you expand on what specific features you want, then? And pls don't use txt spk.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just because two languages have a keyword of the same name doesn't mean they have the same semantics. One really should be more careful with their gold badge privileges.. Voted to reopen.

Comment: That said to answer the question there's no syntactic sugar for this as far as I know, although you could use metaprogramming to achieve something along those lines. But honestly the sole reason to use sealed in Scala doesn't exist in Python (no pattern matching or static compiler warnings) from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to define a type that only allows for `Shape1` or `Shape2`. This is usually done with a type union of the classes defined by the module:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, TypeAlias

# Only necessary if there is some implementation that should be inherited by 
# Shape1 and Shape2.
class _ShapeBase:
    pass

class Shape1(_ShapeBase):
    pass

class Shape2(_ShapeBase):
    pass

Shape: TypeAlias = Shape1 | Shape2

S = TypeVar('S', bound=Shape)

class Array(Generic[S]):
    def shape(self) -> S:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Depending on your implementation, the base class `_ShapeBase` is redundant and can be removed. If none of the subclasses is shared by the classes, having a common base class is redundant.