# Extending the sealed Pushpin class to include more fields

Tags: c#, windows-8, bing-maps, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am developing a windows store app that allows a User to place points on a map and load them from a server. I have this working fine but I need to include more properties than the standard Pushpin class allows (rating / description / user).

Because Pushpin is sealed, I cannot add these fields and use my own object in place of Pushpin. I tried over the past couple of hours to compose my own PointOfInterest class with a Pushpin object inside it however, this approach fails in a number of areas (When I place a point on a map, I want to retrieve more details than just name / tag and have no way of getting a reference back to the original object.)

If anybody has an idea of where to go from here I would like to hear from you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the private members of a sealed class then you are out of luck.

Best you can do is proxy (which you already seem to be doing by including it as a member). Also called  [faking it :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657532/390330)