# Call base method instead of override

Tags: c#, polymorphism

In C#, class `A` contains a public method `Foo()` which does some processing and returns a value.  `protected` method `Bar()`, also in class `A` performs the same logic as `Foo()`, followed by some additional processing, and then returns a value.

In order to avoid duplicating code, `Bar()` calls `Foo()` and uses the return as an intermediate value.

```
class A
{
  public virtual String Foo()
  {
     String computedValue;
     // Compute the value.
     return computedValue;
  }

  protected String Bar()
  {
     String computedValue;
     String intermediateValue = Foo();
     /// More processing to create computedValue from intermediateValue.
     return computedValue;
  }
}
```

Class `B` inherits from `A` and overrides `Foo()`.  The override calls the base class implementation of `Bar()`.

```
class B : A
{
   public override String Foo()
   {
     base.Bar();
   }
}
```

This (of course) goes into an infinite loop until the computer runs out of memory and then yields a stack overflow exception.

The most obvious solution is to rewrite A with a private `FooInternals` method which contains the guts of Foo.  Foo and Bar are then modified to use the results of that method.

Is there a way to force A's `Bar()` to call A's `Foo()` instead of the override?

(I'm almost certainly being way too clever here; this goes completely against polymorphism. But I can't resist the urge to try pushing my knowledge a bit further.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to force A's Bar() to call A's Foo() instead of the override?

Not directly. The simplest refactoring would be to change `Foo` to:

```
public virtual string Foo()
{
    return FooImpl();
}

private string FooImpl()
{
    String computedValue;
    // Compute the value.
    return computedValue;
}
```

Then change `Bar` to call `FooImpl` instead of `Foo`.

(This is probably what you meant in your "most obvious solution" paragraph - which I missed on the first reading, I'm afraid.)

Fundamentally this is just one of those areas where inheritance is problematic. When one virtual method calls another one, that needs to be documented so that subclasses can avoid causing problems - even though it feels like it *should* be an implementation detail. It's this sort of thing that makes me prefer composition over inheritance - where both are reasonable options, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the best/obvious approach.  Just wondering if I might have missed an alternative.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy: Sorry, I managed to miss the paragraph in your answer which describes that. Oops :) But no, that's all you can do really.

Comment: No worries, thanks for verifying that I wasn't overlooking something.